# How can i synchronous test with supertest

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, supertest

### codes:

```
should = require('should')
request = require('supertest')
request = request("stackoverflow.com");

describe "temp", ->

    input_output = [
        { input:"[mocha] [supertest]", output: ["asdf", "asdf"] }
        { input:"아버지가방에들어가신다", output: [ '아버지가방에들어가신다', '아버지', '가방', '에들', '어가', '신다' ] }
        { input:"hi hello", output: ["hi", "hello"] }
    ]

    for item in input_output 

        it "curl https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=#{item.input}", (done) ->

            request
                .get("/search?q=#{item.input}")
                .expect(200)
                .expect (res) ->
                    console.log item.input
                    return
                .end(done)
```

### outputs:

- temp

  - hi hello

    - ✓ curl https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mocha] [supertest] (1017ms)
  - hi hello

    - ✓ curl [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=아버지가방에들어가신다](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%EC%95%84%EB%B2%84%EC%A7%80%EA%B0%80%EB%B0%A9%EC%97%90%EB%93%A4%EC%96%B4%EA%B0%80%EC%8B%A0%EB%8B%A4) (1023ms)
  - hi hello

    - ✓ curl https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hi hello (1124ms)

### i expected below outputs:

- temp

  - [mocha] [supertest]

    - ✓ curl https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mocha] [supertest] (1017ms)
  - 아버지가방에들어가신다

    - ✓ curl [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=아버지가방에들어가신다](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%EC%95%84%EB%B2%84%EC%A7%80%EA%B0%80%EB%B0%A9%EC%97%90%EB%93%A4%EC%96%B4%EA%B0%80%EC%8B%A0%EB%8B%A4) (1023ms)
  - hi hello

    - ✓ curl https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hi hello (1124ms)

i know if i test without callback then i can synchronous test. but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a locally scoped variable inside the test. Something like this:

```
describe "temp", ->

    input_output = [
        { input:"[mocha] [supertest]", output: ["asdf", "asdf"] }
        { input:"아버지가방에들어가신다", output: [ '아버지가방에들어가신다', '아버지', '가방', '에들', '어가', '신다' ] }
        { input:"hi hello", output: ["hi", "hello"] }
    ]

    for item in input_output 

        it "curl http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=#{item.input}", (done) ->
            itemInput = item.input // <-- save in local scope var

            request
                .get("/search?q=#{item.input}")
                .expect(200)
                .expect (res) ->
                    console.log itemInput // <-- use local scope var
                    return
                .end(done)
```